# What's the status of Postgis 2.0 topology support in QGIS?

Tags: postgis, qgis, topology

Having followed the Postgis developments over the past 6 months I have noticed a bunch of features which seem to be incredibly cool especially in the area of topologies and associating calculations on things like intersects, snapping,...

What I am trying to figure out is if anyone has or is working on any plugins which turn these features into native controls within qgis?

Comment: DB Manager supports PostGIS topology in the current version of QGIS (2.18.10).  Seems to have been added in 2012 (so should have been available at least since 2.0).  There is also a PostGIS topology editor QGIS plugin available for editing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PostGIS topology has been a big topic in last weekend's [6th QGIS Developer Meeting](http://linfiniti.com/2011/11/zurich-qgis-developer-meeting-summary-november-2011/)

> Sandro was able to relay a lot of incredibly useful and detailed insight into the PostGIS topological data model to other developers which will prove invaluable in the future as we adopt this new PostGIS capability within QGIS.

More information is available on [Sandro Santilli's blog](http://strk.keybit.net/blog/2011/10/14/postgis-topology-iso-sqlmm-complete/)

> There’s very basic support in the db_manager plugin to open a set of layers which help you visualize your topology, but nothing more than that yet at time of writing.
>   (October 15, 2011 at 7:34 pm)

So yes, this is a work-in-progress feature.